# Adding route with libnl-3-route "Invalid input data or parameter"

Tags: c++, c, routes, netlink

I'm trying to adding route (kernel 2.6.32-57) with libnl-3-routing. I use the documentation :

1. [Netlink library](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/core.html)
2. [Netlink routing](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/route.html)

But the routing chapter is empty... ;)

The problem is the kernel response with "Invalid input data or parameter". I have do some test with use of netlink and i can add a route if i set the following attributes :

1. interface index
2. destination address
3. gateway address
4. mask

   ```
       int ret = 0;
       // Create the route.
       struct rtnl_route* rulesRoute = rtnl_route_alloc();
       rtnl_route_set_iif(rulesRoute, AF_INET); // IPV4

       // Set parameters.
       rtnl_route_set_scope(rulesRoute, RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE);
       rtnl_route_set_table(rulesRoute, RT_TABLE_MAIN);
       rtnl_route_set_protocol(rulesRoute, RTPROT_STATIC);
       uint8_t maskTest = 16;
       rtnl_route_set_scope(rulesRoute, maskTest);

       // Set the destination.
       char destinationAddr[] = "0.0.0.0";
       nl_addr* dstAddr = nl_addr_build(AF_INET, destinationAddr, 8);
       ret = rtnl_route_set_dst(rulesRoute, dstAddr);
       if (ret != 0)
           std::cout << "Error in setting destination route: " << nl_geterror(ret) << std::endl;

       // Set the next hop.
       struct rtnl_nexthop* route_nexthop = rtnl_route_nh_alloc();
       char gatewayAddr[] = "10.110.0.240";
       nl_addr* gatewAddr = nl_addr_build(AF_INET, gatewayAddr, 12);
       rtnl_route_nh_set_gateway(route_nexthop, gatewAddr);
       rtnl_route_nh_set_ifindex(route_nexthop, 2);
       rtnl_route_add_nexthop(rulesRoute, route_nexthop);
       ret = rtnl_route_add(m_nlSocket, rulesRoute, 0);
       if (ret != 0)
           std::cout << "Kernel response:" << nl_geterror(ret) << std::endl;
   ```

I add for information my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.110.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.110.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
```

Thank for helping to solve this issue

Comment: Links are broken :(

Comment: Yea, the project is probably dead, the documentation was never finished and the library was not updated since 2014. We have recently removed all dependencies to this project, and use call to binary (ip route, ip link, ...) instead

Comment: Move all doc to http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/, which is at least working.

Comment: Note about doc: distros start to use https://github.com/thom311/libnl (code of original author, which was hosted on different place is now also on github as a fork: https://github.com/tgraf/libnl), routing is empty here: https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/doc/route.txt#L1262. Fortunately there are examples, see **https://github.com/thom311/libnl/blob/master/src/nl-addr-add.c**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the bad use of function nl_addr_build.

Replace by nl_addr_parse() and that's working.

nl_addr_build : Parse a binary addr

nl_addr_parse : Parse a char* addr like "10.10.1.10"